# How do I use a variable received from request in controller return view

Tags: php, laravel

I've integrated Stripe payment in my Laravel application. After submitting payment I want user to redirect to the link of product he bought.

I'm getting a 'id' variable from 'request' and using it in 'return view' to show specific post in a controller method.

What I've tried

```
return view ('posts.show')->with('post', $request->id);
```

```
return view ('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
```

```
return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
```

Comment: do you want to pass `$request->id` as `post` in blade?

Comment: In a controller method to get user to a specific post blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you're looking for:

```
return redirect('posts/'.$request->id);
```

Comment: It isn't working. Redirecting me to all posts view.

Comment: Then check if the `$request->id` has a value.

Comment: Yes, it returns a value which is the id of post.

Comment: So it must redirect you to that post if you have the correct route in your `web.php` file.

Comment: I can access any post from anywhere, it is just here where I cannot redirect user to a post. So I think this isn't a route problem.

Comment: If you can see `posts/1` and you are sure hat the `$request->id` is not empty and the `$request->id` exists in db then the redirect must work. Can you return `'posts/'.$request->id`?